# Proof with valuations in Liu's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, valuation-theory

I have a question about a claim I found in Liu's book Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves in the Proof of Theorem 8.3.26 (b) page 356:

[image]

In (b) uses the notation of a "center". This can be looked up on previous pages:

By a *center* $x \in X$ of valaution $\nu$ of $K(X)$ Liu means the existence of a morphism $\operatorname{Spec} \ O_{\nu} \to \operatorname{Spec} \ O_{X,x}$ extending canonical inclusion of generic point $Spec \ K(X) \to X$. $O_{\nu}$ is the DVR with maximal ideal $m_{\nu}$ induced by $\nu$.

Also, the proof uses following assertion which we consider as black box:

> ($\alpha$) There exists a blowing-up morphism $X' \to X$ such that the center $x'$
>   of $\nu$ in $X'$ verifies $\operatorname{trdeg}_{k(x)} k(x') ≥ n$.

The **relevant** part I not understand is:

> Let $Y \to X'$ be the normalization. This is a finite
>   morphism because $X'$ is Nagata (Proposition 2.29(b); we can also accept it as black box). Hence $\nu$ admits a center
>   $y \in Y$ which is a point lying above $x'$.

**QUESTION**: Why **finiteness** of $Y \to X'$ allows to lift the center $x'$ with respect to $\nu$ to $Y$?

I think the problem can be translated to commutative algebra as follows:

The center is: if $\nu$ is a non-trivial
valuation of $K(X)$ and has $x \in X$ center, this means simply that $O_{\nu}$ dominates $O_{X,x}$, i.e. we have  $O_{X,x} \subset O_{\nu}$ and $m_x \subset m_{\nu}$ for unique maximal ideals (equivalently: $m_{\nu} \cap O_{X,x}=m_x$.

Assume $\nu$ has center in $x' \in X'$, that is $O_{x',X'} \subset O_{\nu}$ and $O_{\nu}$ dominates $O_{x',X'} $. Let $y_1,...,y_m$ the primages of $x'$ with respect the normalization map. By Nagata argument the normalization map was finite and thus we have finitely many preimages.

futhermore for every $y_i$ the induced maps between local rings $O_{X',x'} \to O_{Y,y_i}$ are finite.

That is the question is why there exist a $y_i$ such that $O_{x',X'} \subset O_{\nu}$ extends to $O_{y_i,Y} \subset O_{\nu}$?

Comment: You can use the facts that if $A \to B$ is a integral ring extension, then $Spec B \to Spec A$ is surjective and if $A \to B$ is finite, then it is integral.

Comment: maybe use fact valuation rings are integrally closed. So if $a \in O_{Y, y_i}$ then by finiteness (or integrality) of $O_{X,x} \to O_{Y, y_i}$, $a$ is integral over $O_{X,x}$ and hence integral over $O_{V,v}$. Since $O_{V,v}$ is integrally closed, then $a \in O_{V,v}$. This seems to suggest $v$ is centered on all the $O_{Y, y_i}$ but that doesn't sound right, so maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @Youngsu: ok, so I assume you suggest to set $A:=O_{X',x'}$ and $B:= O_{Y,y_i}$. Then as you said, $A \to B$ is integral and $Spec B \to Spec A$ is surjective. But I not see how this obseravation help to solve the problem.

Comment: @usr0192: I think that's exactly the right idea. More technically, recall that $O_{X',x'} \to O_{Y,y_i}$ was by construction the normalization. And normalizations have following universal property: Let $\bar{R}$ normalization of $R$ and $R \to S$ a ring map with $S$ integrally closed (our $O_{\nu}$ is int closed as you said) then we obtain a factorization $\bar{R} \to S$. That is what we were looking for. But your remark is correct, it seems that we have shown a more stonger statement: the center extends over **every** preimage $y_i$.

Comment: Why do you think in your last sentence that there runs something wrong with this argument? It looks correct...

Comment: @MortyPB the argument seemed correct to me, but i was just surprised i proved something stronger, so i wasn’t confident. and i’m not an expert in the area